# MVC3 - service references

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

We have a web service for our MVC3 app that communicates with our Oracle database. When I'm debugging, I use the Web.Debug.config file to point to the copy on our development server that connects to our development database (system.serviceModel->client->endpoint). And our Web.Release.config points to the one on our live server that connects to our production database.

Sometimes we modify the development web service in order to test new functionality.

My question is, when I want to publish to the live server, do I need to refresh my service reference in my project before publishing if we have different functionality in the development copy of the web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to this depends on what the changes are.

If the changes are just functionality "behind the scenes" and do not impact the interface (ie, the method names and parameters) then you probably won't need a refresh.

If a new method is added, or a parameter changes types, or new types are accepted or returned then you will need a refresh.

Comment: A lot of times we add new functionality and/or new functions/classes.